# joomla website loading differently when going to a different page

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

We have uploaded joomla to our ubuntu server here is the specs.

> PHP Built On Linux angel.sistech.co.za 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu
>   SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64
>  Database
>   Version   5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
>  Database
>   Collation latin1_swedish_ci
>  PHP Version   5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6
>  Web
>   Server    Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
>  WebServer to PHP
>   Interface apache2handler
>  Joomla! Version  Joomla! 3.4.0 Stable [
>   Ember ] 24-February-2015 23:00 GMT
>  Joomla! Platform Version   Joomla
>   Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT
>  User
>   Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36

When you open the page at http://www.saharasystems.co.za/tna it looks fine, but when you go to another page it looks like the models breaks. Also when you go back to home he module breaks. the modules is rocksproket and news show.

I have updated it to the newest ones and my permissions and ownership is set to `www-data` and 755 for folders and 644 for files. 
kan any one help me please.

Comment: By inspecting your code, I suspect something goes wrong with your system cache and the module sprocket-headlines.

Comment: Thank you we cleared the cache on the server and enabled mod cache and it works

Comment: You are welcome. Added the above as an answer to the question too (a little extended).

Comment: Also, do not forget to vote the answer as best, if you think it is of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what you say, it has probably to do with the system cache and the module `sprochet-headlines`. Try clearing your cache and check your `mod cache` configuration.